# Speed up data I/O in H5 files

Tags: h5py

I have a H5 file which holds one large dataset `DATA`, `1700000x224x224x3`. The dataset is not chunked. That is,

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('large_file.h5', 'r')
dset = f['DATA']
dset.chunks # <- empty
```

Q1: Is this advisable?

I have a process which needs to infinitely keep reading entries from `DATA` as `f['DATA'][i, 224, 224, 3]`. Per my understanding, H5PY automatically caches data and the rate at which older chunks are dropped is given by `rdcc_w0` flag wherein a value of 0 would be most ideal if I were to keep reading files infinitely.

Q2: Will my H5 file, which has no chunks, be cached?

Comment: The key to reducing the memory footprint is to only read slices of your data as you need it (for example, if `ds=f['DATA']`, you can read a slice with `arr=ds[0,:,:,:]` to get the first row/image. Chunking only improves I/O if it was properly defined. Chunk size/shape used to read slices. In your case, you might want `chunks=(10, 224, 224, 3)` (assumes you want to read slices along the 0-axis). If you find I/O is too slow w/out chunking, you can create a new file and copy the data with chunked datasets.

Comment: Thanks @kcw78, I find that if you haven't chunked the data, i.e, stored as a contiguous array, then data caching doesn't happen. However, this is questionable because I need to perform precise tests.